# iPhone Back button text iOS5+ not showing up?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uibutton, back

i have loaded a custom back button with [uibarbutton appearance] but i dont know how to alter the text on the custom image. The code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:[UIImageimageNamed:@"someimage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not required to set title or text for it, navigation system of `ios` it does itself, only you have to assign your custom button to navigation bar's `backbutton`

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:nil action:nil];
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;
```

Answer (score 0):

The text on the back button is determined by the `title` property of the view controller that the back button would navigate to (i.e. the previous view controller on the navigation controller's stack).

Answer (score 0):

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back"
style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
target:self action:@selector(back:)] autorelease];
```